# Different values of pi?

Tags: php, precision, pi

```
ini_set('precision', 64);    
echo M_PI."<br>";
echo pi()."<br>";
echo "3.14159265358979323846264338327950<br>";
```

For reference I've used http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/digits/100

If you compare the output you get the following:

```
3.1415926535898
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
3.14159265358979323846264338327950
```

So what's with the precision value of `pi()`? It seems its totally off. Yes, I know pi is irrational, but at least to 100 significant digits it should be accurate?

Can anyone confirm this problem, and is it possible to explain why after 16 digits it goes wrong in php?

Comment: `echo "3.14159265358979323846264338327950<br>";`-> `<br>`is looking bad there. Don't you think so?

Comment: It's because of how floats are stored in php

Comment: Maybe it's because ["the returned float has a precision based on the precision directive in php.ini, which defaults to 14."](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pi.php).. can't confirm, I do not code in PHP

Comment: Why exactly are you using PHP if you need accuracy to 100 decimal points?

Comment: in 64 bits you can store int with 20 digits, do you think you can store float with more digits in it and have it precise?

Comment: so set_ini('precision', 64) is meaningless?  and can you type cast float to double-floating point precision?

Comment: @Tigger, so in any number, the number is should be rounded...but its not rounding its totally wrong after 16 digits...the point I'm making is how do I make sure that rounding occurs at 16 digits vs. getting a totally wrong value at 20 digits.  I don't need accuracy at 100 decimal points I was just making a point that its way off and not a rounding issue.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bcmath extensions manual page the following is presented:

```
//bcpi function with Gauss-Legendre algorithm
//by Chao Xu (Mgccl)

function bcpi($precision){
  $n=0;
    $limit = ceil(log($precision)/log(2))-1;
    bcscale($precision+6);
    $a = 1;
    $b = bcdiv(1,bcsqrt(2));
    $t = 1/4;
    $p = 1;
    while($n < $limit){
        $x = bcdiv(bcadd($a,$b),2);
        $y = bcsqrt(bcmul($a, $b));
        $t = bcsub($t, bcmul($p,bcpow(bcsub($a,$x),2)));
        $a = $x;
        $b = $y;
        $p = bcmul(2,$p);
        ++$n;
    }
    return bcdiv(bcpow(bcadd($a, $b),2),bcmul(4,$t),$precision);
}

echo bcpi(64);
echo "<br>3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923";
```

It seems therefore, that ini_set('precision',64); doesn't do anything constructive for the regular php math functions (>15), but bcmath extension ignores the setting entirely.

So to work in precision >= 16 use bcmath extension
otherwise ini_set works up to 15

And @Progman's answer that float/double storing rules still apply - means that there is a cap on 15 decimal points (even though php stores all floats as double)

Answer (score 3):

The "problem" is that the value of `M_PI` (which is the same value returned by `pi()`) is hardcoded.

From the [`php_math.h`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/2bac0452145604e3a8e1bd557dbf0aef09fc5222/ext/standard/php_math.h#L109) file:

> ```
> #ifndef M_PI
> #define M_PI           3.14159265358979323846  /* pi */
> #endif
> ```

Changing the precision doesn't change the already defined constant value. Additionally the usual "how are float/double numbers are stored" still apply.